# Symfony 5 Multiple independent unique fields are not validated

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony5, symfony-validator

I'm trying to validate unique username and email in database.

Imagine this scenario in DB Users table:

| username | email |
| --- | --- |
| aykon | aykon@aykon.sk |
| aykon94 | aykon94@aykon.sk |

I have this code in User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, groups={"register", "edit"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, groups={"register", "edit"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

And this is my register function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="api_auth_register", methods={"POST"})
 * @return JsonResponse|RedirectResponse
 */
public function register(
    Request $request,
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    CustomSerializer $serializer,
    ValidatorInterface $validator,
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
) {
    $user = $serializer->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), User::class, 'json');
    assert($user instanceof User);
    $errors = $validator->validate($user, null, 'register');

    if ($errors->count() !== 0) {
        return new JsonResponse(
            $serializer->serializer->serialize($errors, 'json'),
            Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
            [],
            true,
        );
    }

    $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->json([], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

When I sent this payload:

```
{
    "username": "aykon",
    "email": "aykon@aykon.sk",
    "password": "password"
}
```

I get correct `422` response with error that username and email is already used!

But when I sent this:

```
{
    "username": "aykon94",
    "email": "aykon@aykon.sk",
    "password": "password"
}
```

I get **incorrect** `422` response with error that **email** is already used!

> How can I enforce symfony to continue validation and show error also
> for username?

This is not big issue during register because when I change email to pass validation smt like `aykon199@aykon.sk` it will show validation error on username. I can live with that.

But when I try to edit user for example `aykon`, meaning I have username and email already in DB, and I change only username to `aykon94`, validation stops at non unique email `aykon@aykon.sk` and it ignores it because it is the same object. I got error from DB

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username"
```

**EDIT:**
Provided edit function:

```
    /** @Route("/{id}", methods={"PUT"}) */
    public function updateUser(
        Request $request,
        ValidatorInterface $validator,
        UserRepository $userRepository,
        CustomSerializer $serializer,
        string $id
    ): JsonResponse {
        $groups = ['user', 'currentUser', 'userPicture'];

        $oldUser = $userRepository->find($id);

        if ($oldUser === null) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }

        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(UserVoter::EDIT_PROFILE, $oldUser);

        $user = $serializer->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), User::class, 'json');
        assert($user instanceof User);

        $oldUser->setEmail($user->getEmail());
        $oldUser->setUsername($user->getUsername());
        $oldUser->setBio($user->getBio());

        //        $validationGroups = $user->isEnabled() ? ['default', 'enabled'] : null;
        $validationGroups = ['default', 'enabled', 'edit'];
        $errors = $validator->validate($oldUser, null, $validationGroups);

        if ($errors->count() !== 0) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                $serializer->serializer->serialize($errors, 'json'),
                Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                [],
                true,
            );
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of the edit action?

Comment: @Artem Function is in Edit :) I know that I should have used DTO, I'm just doing quick project with refactor later on :)